# Using different css frameworks for different pages using Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing a website in angular 9 and that website will have an administrative panel. This panel will not use the layout of the website nor will the website use the layout of the panel. I will use Angular Material for the panel and the website will be a simple css.

However, I don't want the styles to be present on these two pages, as I will make the site as light as possible.

Example:
     www.mywebsite.com/ -> Normal css (Without showing Angular Material)
     www.mywebsite.com/ -> Angular Material (without showing the normal css)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont think its possible in angular, if you want to use your normal webpage which is created using html,css,js then add that in assets folder by creating a new folder and in link it to your navigation, by this way you can achieve what you required.

Comment: please explain in more detail what exactly you are looking for also both the routes you've mentioned are same so I'm not able to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Will the admin panel use the same components?

Comment: sorry guys, i've forgot my own question...
Let me say by other way.: On my website i have a footer and header, out of <outlet-router> tag, that doesn't change in any router change. BUT, when go to any admin route, i don't want to use the footer and header that are outside of outlet-router, more clear now?

Comment: @David, no. The cmoponents will not be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with angular.

Reached this creating an workspace and 2 projects inside it.

```
ng new my-workspace --create-application false
```

After that.:

```
ng generate application sample1
ng generate application sample2
```